# How to register new schema in cocoa/objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am looking for a simple tutorial (framework?) that will explain me basic steps that I have to do to register new schema and handle it with my app written in objective-c and cocoa.

Explanation: Some apps like Adium, has registered schemas. Schema for the user is an URI like "adiumxtra://www.adiumxtras.com/download/6636". So, when the user clicks on it (in a web browser, or chat etc.), Mac OS understands that Adium is responsible for protocol "adiumxtra" and directs user's request to Adium and Adium processes content on the given URI.

I would like to do something similar. I already checked Adium's source, but "schema" handling is implemented in a quite tricky way... Maybe somebody can explain it to me in a "little bit" easy way? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean URL schemes, not schemas (which would refer to either XML or Sync Services).

The first step is to have a [CFBundleURLTypes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/PListKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102207) entry in your app's Info.plist.

The second step is to [implement an Apple Event handler to handle the getURL event](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-BBCIDFHG).

Comment: I already implemented all needed functionality with URL schemes!

Answer (score 2):

For the iPhone, Craig Hockenberry has a good example, with source code, of how to use custom URL schemes in his post [here](http://furbo.org/2008/10/01/redacted/).